# What are possible treatments for mouth ulcers?

Tags: pain, treatment

I am suffering from mouth ulcers, and as a result I am not able to eat properly and suffer with a lot of mouth pain.n I am not able to sleep properly due to my busy schedule.

I consulted many doctors and tried many remedies, but have not found anything that gives me relief.

What else I can do? What the possible treatments for mouth ulcers?

Answer (score 2):

I had a same situation due to allergic reaction. Hives and mouth ulcers. I mixed 50/50 Mylanta and Childrens Benedryl and swished. The Mylanta coated the mouth which allowed me to eat without the pain and burning, The Childrens Benedryl helped with the ulcers and hives. It's also okay to swallow. You didn't mention the cause or the remedies you have tried. This is one that helped me. Good Luck.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Crazy as it seems, this site requires sources which support answers, even on 'common sense' answers. We appreciate that this is a burden; consider how appreciated sources on answers to your own questions would be. Please see the [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about the site. Thanks, and again, welcome! (Btw, I like your answer, and used to recommend this treatment as well for kids, swish and spit or apply with a Q-tip for cooperative kids and adults. Dosage matters.)

Answer (score 2):

Recurrent aphthous stomatitis (RAS; aphthae; canker sores) is not uncommon (>20% of the population of the UK) and can be very painful and disruptive. In addition to consulting a doctor, please consider asking your dentist (dentists deal with this a lot) or a specialist of the mouth (such as an oral surgeon). It may be as simple as your toothpaste choice, or as complex as an autoimmune disorder. In any case, they should help you treat it symptomatically, and may find an underlying cause.

There are three "kinds" of RAS based on size and number of ulcers: minor, major, and herpetiform.

In addition to treating any underlying disorder, common recommendations - among others - include maintaining good diet (with some attention to B<sub>12</sub>), oral hygiene, avoiding toothpastes with SLS, and *possibly* using mouthwashes containing chlorhexidine or triclosan.

For the occasional aphthous ulcer, there is a sticky paste you can apply to the ulcer called *Orabase*. It has a topical anesthetic and temporarily relieves pain, so that you can eat, sleep, etc. There is also a viscous lidocaine 2% solution which can be swished/spit. The downside of this is that you can't taste anything, as your tongue gets numbed as well. Alternatively, you can apply it to the lesions with a Q-tip.

Under the supervision of a physician, topical corticosteroids can sometimes control symptoms that are incapacitating. There are corticosteroid preparations in *orabase*, gels, and other.

There are prescription antibiotic oral preparations with which one can rinse and spit, usually containing a tetracycline derivative, or tetracycline plus nicotinamide which may provide relief and reduce ulcer duration and recurrence. If RAS fails to respond to these measures, oral  immunomodulators may be required, again under specialist supervision.

Complementary and Alternative Medicine recommendations include vitamin supplements, bee propolis, various herbs, and honey.

<sub>[Oral medicine — Update for the dental practitioner Aphthous and other common ulcers](http://www.nature.com/bdj/journal/v199/n5/full/4812649a.html)</sub>
<sub>[Treatment strategies for recurrent aphthous ulcers](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Robert_Barrons/publication/12137206_Treatment_strategies_for_recurrent_oral_aphthous_ulcers/links/0c96053be7aa3553bb000000.pdf)</sub>
<sub>[A double blind, randomised placebo controlled trial of topical 2% viscous lidocaine in improving oral intake in children with painful infectious mouth conditions](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2431/11/106/)</sub>
<sub>[Aphthous ulcers (recurrent)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2943778/)</sub>
<sub>[Cyanocobalamin May be Beneficial in the Treatment of Recurrent Aphthous Ulcers Even When Vitamin B12 Levels Are Normal.](http://journals.lww.com/amjmedsci/Abstract/2008/11000/Cyanocobalamin_May_be_Beneficial_in_the_Treatment.2.aspx)</sub>
<sub>[Stomatitis](http://www.unboundmedicine.com/5minute/view/5-Minute-Clinical-Consult/116570/all/Stomatitis) <- an *Unbound Medicine 5-minute Clinical Consult*</sub>